# Change color of text when you scroll over a Image background?

Tags: css, text, scroll, colors

When hover the text `position: fixed;` over the Image background in scrolling then the text change the color, and please tell me how thank you

like this example, I edited with paint

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qiPa.jpg)  [Exemple2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kUWP.png) [Exemple3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YorND.jpg)

Don't tell me to use "mix-blend-mode" because it doesn't let me choose the colors

this result of mix-blend-mode: difference;

[mix-blend-mode: difference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTDGH.jpg)

Comment: Hello Omar, welcome to SO! Could you please tell us a bit more about this situation? Does the text have "position: fixed" applied? If not, there might be a workaround, but we need to understand what is it that you're trying to do (how is it that the text scrolls over the background)

Comment: Hello Drago, Thanks, Of course position: fixed; like the exemple

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If the element is fixed in position, sadly I cannot see any other alternative rather then blend modes. There are other workarounds possible to show text in two different colors, but they will not work with `position: fixed`